# Upload Download xlsx file in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload xlsx file and read it's content to insert into database.

I completed download xlsx but facing issue in upload and reading the content

Here is the jsp:

```
<div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >
                        <input style="width:200px" class="admin_search_btn" type=file name="uploadxls" value=""  />
                     </div>
                <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >  
                    <button type="submit" class="admin_search_btn">Submit</button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="submit" class="admin_search_btn">Cancel</button>
                </div>
```

How should I map this to controller to upload the file on server and read it's content?

Comment: Could you provide the `<form>` tag as well as the controller that does not work yet?

Comment: @Markus: still testing the code

Answer (score 0):

A file upload differs from a normal post (POST, GET). If you follow this tutorial [Link](http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) or [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s08.html) you will see what you missed:

• a form tag, that allows a "multipart" post

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
```

• a servlet that handles your upload

Please give us more details what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> **Upload File to Server:**

Uploading a file on server has been already answered with an excellent explanation in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) .

> **Reading xlsx file using java:**

Use Apache-poi to read its content from the file.Apache POI is a Java library to work with different Microsoft Office file formats such as Excel, Power point, Visio, MS Word etc.

I found [this article](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/) useful as I have also followed this article to get started with Apache-poi.

Comment: thanks, but it is using servlet and I am working in spring mvc.